# have method return false if a block of code is taking to long

Tags: java, multithreading, timer, runnable

Having trouble with threads and timers.   I need this method to execute some code but if the code takes to long the method should return false.  Here is what I am doing:

```
    public boolean handShake() {

        java.util.Timer t = new java.util.Timer();
    t.schedule(new java.util.TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                if (threadSuccess = false) {
                    System.out.println("will kill");
//not sure but this is how I read you should kill threads?
                    Thread t = handShakeThread;
                    handShakeThread = null;
                    t.interrupt();
                    System.out.println("Should have killed thread");
                }
            }
        }, 8000);

        try {
            System.out.println("Going to start threads");

            handShakeThread = new Thread(new HandShakeThread());
//handShakeThread is a field (Threat) and HandShakeThread is a class extending Runnable
            handShakeThread.start();
        System.out.println("Thread started");
            handShakeThread.join();
            System.out.println("finished");
            return threadSuccess;
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The timer task never appears to be called.  It sits there waiting and waiting.  What can I do?

Extra info:
The handShakeThread is reading from a network.  If it completes the reading successfully, field threadSuccess is set to true.  The idea is that if reading from the network is taking to long, there should be a time out.  Is this the best way of doing this?

Comment: I would recommend using the Java 5+ concurrent APIs. For example, you can use an ExecutorService (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html), which gives you some methods to specify a timeout.

Comment: probably unrelated, but you write `if(threadSuccess = false)` which sets `threadSuccess` to false and does not enter the if block. You probably want `if(!threadSuccess)`.

Comment: You ought to be able to set a timeout on your network call - like `setSoTimeout(<time>)` on the socket or similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try re-writing your HandShakeThread as a Runnable and doing something like this. If the Runnable does not complete after 8 seconds, the method will return false.

```
public boolean handShake() {
    Runnable handShakeTask = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // do network stuff
        }
    };
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
    try {
        Future<Boolean> future = executorService.submit(networkTask, true);
        executorService.shutdown();
        return future.get(8, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (TimeoutException ex) {
        return false;
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        // handle exception
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, rolfl. I added a shutdown call to the ExecutorService.

Comment: Unless the 'working' thread is designed to handle being interrupted, it will still keep going. Fortunately, in this case, because Java's blocking IO mecanisms are well behaved, it will likely work

Comment: Hi thanks a lot this looks like exactly what I need.  Would you/someone be able to explain a little on how the code works?  For starters which line tells the ExecutorService to make use of the Runnable above?  Also I see no mention of 8 seconds.  Or have you used 2 seconds just as an example?  Any explanation on the lines of code used would be greatly appreciated - I am a beginner at threads.  Thanks!!!!

Comment: The `.submit` call is what tells the ExecutorService to schedule the Runnable. The service was initiated with a single-Thread threadpool, so it's fairly safe to assume the Runnable will be run as soon as you call `submit`. If you call `get` on the returned Future, it blocks your current thread until the process completes, but if you call `get` with a timeout (which I accidentally had as 2 seconds instead of 8)--the Future throws a TimeoutException if the process is still running by that time. This keeps your main thread from being blocked, although the Runnable will continue to run.

Comment: If you did want to stop the thread executing the runnable you could call boolean cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning) on the future, passing in a true value. This will attempt to interupt the thread, but does not guarantee to do so.